# TAB completon and mc problems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, command-line-interface

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=8.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=intrepid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 8.10"
```

This is the server version.

When I ssh into it, I encounter the following problems:

**Problem 1**

tab completion behaves weird to the point of being unusable:

```
> cd ~/<press TAB>
-sh: <( compgen -d -- '/home/dmitriid/' ): No such file or directory

> vi ~/.<press TAB>
<( compgen -d -- '/home/dmitriid/.' ): No such file or directory
-sh: <( eval compgen -f -X '*.@(o|so|so.!(conf)|a|rpm|gif|GIF|jp?(e)g|
JP?(E)G|mp3|MP3|mp?(e)g|MPG|avi|AVI|asf|ASF|ogg|OGG|class|CLASS)' -- 
$(quote_readline $cur) ): No such file or directory

> nano ~/.<press TAB>
./              .bash_logout    .mc/            .viminfo
../             .bashrc         .mysql_history  
.aptitude/      .erlang.cookie  .profile        
.bash_history   .gitconfig      .ssh/
```

Is there a way to fix that?

**Problem 2**

I use mc quite a lot. I often do a Ctrl+O to hide panels and work in the shell. In my case:

1. Ctrl + O hides panels
2. Any keypress brings the panels back

Is there a way to fix that as well?

Thank you!

Comment: paste the output of "printenv". I have a suspicion that $HOME is wrong.

Comment: there is also mention of a bug in bash regarding funny characters, so maybe there is home directory with unprintable characters?

Comment: Nope, all characters in ~ are ascii

Output of printenv is:

$ printenv
TERM=xterm-color
SHELL=/bin/sh
SSH_CLIENT=217.12.113.58 52846 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
USER=dmitriid
LS_COLORS=colorlist
MAIL=/var/mail/dmitriid
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
PWD=/home/dmitriid
LANG=en_CA
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/dmitriid
LOGNAME=dmitriid
SSH_CONNECTION=connection
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/printenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. It turns out the solution was dumb and simple. The key was — no interactive shell in mc.

The answer lies here: http://www.ibiblio.org/mc/FAQ

> 6.6 When I use Ctrl-O I don't get a subshell.  How do I fix this?
>
> Only bash, tcsh and zsh can be used as subshell.  Use one of those
>    shells as your default shell, and it will be used as subshell in GNU
>    Midnight Commander.

So I decided to change the shell:

```
> which bash
/bin/bash
> sudo chsh -s /bin/bash my_user_name
> grep ^my_user_name /etc/password
my_user_name:x:1002:1002::/home/my_user_name:/bin/bash
```

Note /bin/bash at the end of the passwd file. It means the shell is now changed.

After i logged out and then logged back in — voila, everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's something wrong with your home directory. Can you do a `ls ~` and tell us what's up?

Comment: > ls ~
    apache-couchdb-0.9.0         backup  Django-1.0.2-final             
    gitrepo  sources.list  www-libs  www-old
    apache-couchdb-0.9.0.tar.gz  data    Django-1.0.2-final.tar.gz  libs         
    www           www-new

Answer (score 0):

You `.bashrc` is sourcing `/etc/bash_completion` who uses `compgen` go generate completion for several know commands (such as `cd` and `vi`) but not to `nano`.

For some reason `compgen` has a problem completing files and directories in your home folder.
One quick option to fix this is to comment out the following lines in your `.bashrc`.

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
 fi
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't work :( Same problem :(

Comment: correct that. doing reinstallation of bash-related commands and commenting out these lines resulted in this: if I log in, the problem persists. If I run bash, the new prompt behaves as expected (except for the mc problem)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your first problem is that you use /bin/sh as shell. Even when this is linked to bash, completion doesn't work.

Change your shell to bash: chsh -s /bin/bash
and relogin.

Comment: Yep, that' s what I did in the end (see my answer above)